# JSON to datatable - How to deserialize

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I have this very simple JSON string:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 33306,
        "sport": {
            "id1": "FB",
            "id2": "HB"
        }
     }
}
```

I can't understand how to return a datatable from this string.

I have tried to use this code but it's not working:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Comment: What is `DataTable`, here? If you hover your mouse over the `datatable` tag, you will see that it is an ambiguous term. Also, what does "it is not working" mean? What happens? Any error messages? How can we take your code and recreate your problem for ourselves?

Comment: There are several JSON libraries for Java. Which one are you using? The only JSON-related library I found which contains an object called `JsonConvert` is [this one](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm) - but it's for .Net, not Java. In fact, your code does not look like Java code...

Comment: Hi! I'm using c# in .net:  System.Data.DataTable and Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.  I think it has something to do with missing brackets in my json string?

Comment: You need to change the question's tags. Currently you are reaching a `java` audience.

Comment: Ahhhh...now I see the java tag..that was not my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you have to flatten all json properties, after this to convert to DataTable

```
    var jObj = (JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["data"];
    var properties = jObj.Properties().ToList();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
    {
        var prop = properties[i];
        if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            foreach (var p in ((JObject)prop.Value).Properties())
                jObj.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name + " " + p.Name, p.Value));
            prop.Remove();
        }
    }

    DataTable dt = new JArray { jObj }.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

output

```
[
  {
    "id": 33306,
    "sport id1": "FB",
    "sport id2": "HB"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanx for answer! I got the same problem with this solution as I have experienced before: "Unexpected json token...."
http://sharing.profixio.com/uploads/2023-02-15_072223.png

Comment: I do suspect the json string is somehow invalid. Will check!!

Comment: @OleEngvoll I always post only tested code. This code  is  working properly at my mashine. Your json must be different.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this in two steps.

1. Deserialize into a .net object whose structure matches that of the JSON
2. Populate a DataTable with the properties of that object

#### Step 1 - Deserialize

We need to define some classes to receive the deserialized data. The names of the classes aren't particularly important (as long as they're meaningful to you), however the names of the properties of those classes need to match the names of the corresponding elements in the JSON.

First the outermost class, which is the shape of the JSON you want to deserialize.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public DataElement Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now we need to define the shape of `DataElement`.

```
public class DataElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SportElement Sport { get; set; }
}
```

And now we need to define the shape of SportElement.

```
public class SportElement
{
    public string Id1 { get; set; }
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
}
```

The implementation above is fairly rigid and assumes that the shape of the JSON doesn't change from one document to the next. If, however, you expect the shape to vary, for example, if the `sport` element could could contain any number of `id1`, `id2`, `id3`, ... `id100` etc elements, then you can throw away the `SportElement` class and use a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) to represent that element instead.

```
public class DataElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Sport { get; set; }
}
```

Which of those two approaches to use will depend on how predictable the structure of the JSON is (or whether or not it's under your control). I find that using a dictionary is a good way of coping with JSON produced by 3rd party applications which aren't under my control, but the resulting objects aren't as easy to work with as those where I know exactly what shape the JSON will always be and can create a strongly-typed class structure representing that shape.

Whichever approach you choose, the usage is the same:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);
```

#### Step 2 - Populate the DataTable from the object

How to do this step will depend on what you want the DataTable to look like (which is not clear from the question). For example, you might want it to look like this (which I think is what [Serge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75403764/16563198) would return).

| id | sport id1 | sport id2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33306 | FB | HB |

Or (if for example the `sport` element could contain any number of `id1`, `id2` and so on elements) you might want it to look like this.

| id | sport |
| --- | --- |
| 33306 | id1: FB |
| 33306 | id2: HB |

Or you might want some different representation altogether. Sorry if that's an incomplete answer, if you want to update the question with what you'd expect the DataTable to look like then I can update this answer with more detail on how to go about step 2.